# maze solver using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I was given some code that builds a maze and whatever else is needed, the abstract maze class contains a abstract method 'makeMove (int row, int col)' this is the method I am trying to write to solve the maze, moving left, right, up, down.

I just started working on this, and below is all I have so far.

```
int MAX_ROWS = endRow + 1;
int MAX_COLS = endCol + 1;
boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
protected void makeMove( int row, int col )
{
    boolean found = false;
    //boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
    //visited[startRow][startCol] = true;
    if (row < 0 || row >= MAX_ROWS  || col < 0 || col >= MAX_COLS  || visited[row][col] || maze[row][col] == 1)
        return;

    visited[row][col] = true;
    found = row == endRow && col == endCol;

    if (!found) {
        makeMove(row, col - 1);
        makeMove(row, col + 1);
        makeMove(row - 1, col);
        makeMove(row + 1, col);
    }

    }
    /*if(row == endRow && col == endCol) {
        found = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row][col - 1]!=1 && !visited[row][col]) { // move left
        makeMove(row, col -1);
        visited[row][col -1] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row - 1][col]!=1 && !visited[row-1][col]) { // move up
        makeMove(row-1, col);
        visited[row-1][col] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row][col + 1]!=1 && !visited[row][col + 1]) { // move right
        makeMove(row, col + 1);
        visited[row][col + 1] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row + 1][col]!=1 && !visited[row + 1][col]) { // move down
        makeMove(row + 1, col);
        visited[row + 1][col] = true;
    }*/
```

Ok I have the code working to where I no longer get the error.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Don't forget to correctly use `{}` in your if/else statements.

Comment: I edited code, did it fix what you meant? and is the visited[][] look like it is being done correctly?

Comment: Why don't you just run it and see if it's correct? Though personally I'd prefer to have the base case at the beginning of the method rather than at invocation.

Comment: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/ also take guidance.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi running code as I have edited above gives a null pointer exception, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean[][] visited = null;
```

declares a local variable. You need to declare it as a member of the class so it can persist between invocations of `makeMove`. You'll also want to initialize it properly:

```
boolean[][] visited = new boolean[...][...];
```

You also need to perform bounds checking. After a few recursive calls you'll hit the edge of the maze and go outside the range of the array.

Thus the code might look like:

```
int MAX_ROWS = ...
int MAX_COLS = ...

boolean[][] visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

protected void makeMove(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= MAX_ROWS 
     || col < 0 || col >= MAX_COLS 
     || visited[row][col] 
     || maze[row][col] == 1)
        return;

    visited[row][col] = true;
    found = row == endRow && col == endCol;

    if (!found) {
        makeMove(row, col - 1);
        makeMove(row, col + 1);
        makeMove(row - 1, col);
        makeMove(row + 1, col);
    }
}
```

where `MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLS` correspond to the dimensions of the maze. Note that by default `visited` is initialized with all `false`. If you want to call this method multiple times on different mazes, you should wrap it in a method that will reinitialize `visited`.

Comment: so instead of how I have it, it should be

Comment: boolean[][]visited = new boolean[startRow][startCol], and just get rid of boolean[][] visited = null?

Comment: also, if I changed to this I then get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error, which I assume is because something is wrong in the move methods?

Comment: sorry just noticed the last part of bounds checking lol, you were right that's the error i'm getting. I'm not familiar with how to deal with it in this way, I need something to check in each if statement?

Comment: or would putting them all in a while statement be a better solution?

Comment: I understand, just having a little trouble implementing, would both MAX_ROWS and MAX_COLS be determined by maze.length??

Comment: For now I just need to go from top left to bottom right, so I could do MAX_ROWS = endRow, and MAX_COLS = endCol; however I will be writing this program again where the path is not that simple so I'm not sure how that would look...

Comment: @user2745043 The code I provided should work; what are you having trouble with? I assumed rows and columns use the starting-at-zero indexing convention so `MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLS` should be bigger than any actual row and column value (eg. `endRow + 1`, `endCol + 1`). If your maze has a border, go ahead and make it any size as long as it's bigger. If not, make it precisely the right size so it fits.

Comment: I've updated my code to show what you have suggested. When ran like this I keep getting a StackOverFlowError and it says line 23 (int MAX_ROWS = endRow + 1;) line 35 (makeMove(row, col - 1);) and line 36 (makeMove(row, col + 1);)

Comment: I figured out my problem I didn't have some things in right place like you had, It's now working thanks for all your help!